# LINQ Where filtering with lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have code like this:

```
.Where(o => o.Parents.Contains(name))
```

The above code does not work because `Parents` contain a list of `Parent` objects, which in turn have a property `Name`. I want to check against the `Name` property, but it's a list so how could I do this check? So I want the `Where` to be `true` when any of the `Parent` objects in the list have `Name` property set to `name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code snippet:

```
.Where(o => o.Parents.Any(p => p.Name == name))
```

Comment: Yup, that did it! Edited to suit better to the question. I'll accept when the magical 10mins are over.

Comment: `p => p.Contains(name)` won't work because he wants to check against the `Name` property of `Parents`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple fix for this: use more LINQ.

```
.Where(o => o.Parents.Any(p => p.Name == name))
```

As an alternative, you could use the slightly more verbose (but equally lazy)

```
.Where(o => o.Parents.Select(p => p.Name).Contains(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Any to check for a specific condition inside a collection of objects where you want to check for a specific property.

```
.Where(o => o.Childs.Any(child => child.Name == o.Name));
```